# Codeigniter 4 - get instance in helper function

Tags: php, codeigniter

how can i get in ci4 instance into helper function? $CI =&get_instance(); <- that was in version 3, how does this go in version Codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 5):

I **[made](https://gist.github.com/mohammadhzp/c4c87352852515f4ad74f3a75d52264c)** a gist for it. here is a way to do it.

1. Create a helper file, you can name it whatever you want.
2. Add the following codes to the helper you just created.

**Content of the helper file: i.e: utility_helper.php**

```
<?php

$CI_INSTANCE = [];  # It keeps a ref to global CI instance

function register_ci_instance(\App\Controllers\BaseController &$_ci)
{
    global $CI_INSTANCE;
    $CI_INSTANCE[0] = &$_ci;
}


function &get_instance(): \App\Controllers\BaseController
{
    global $CI_INSTANCE;
    return $CI_INSTANCE[0];
}
```

3. Call `register_ci_instance($this)` at the very beginning of your **base controller**
4. Now you may use `get_instance()` where ever you want just like CI3: `$ci = &get_instance()`

There are three notes I want to mention

- I tested on **PHP8** only.
- I'm not sure if `&` is needed when calling `get_instance`. however, you have the option to use any form you want. so calling `$ci = get_instance()` is ok too, but you may do `$ci = &get_instance()` as you wish.
- Make sure you change `\App\Controllers\BaseController` to something appropiate(**i.e: your base controller**). type hinting is great since IDEs understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a common helper to keep the controller instance. Suppose here it  is `common_helper.php`

```
$CI4 = new \App\Controllers\BaseController;

function register_CI4(&$_ci)
{
    global $CI4;
    $CI4 = $_ci;
}
```

In your `BaseController`

```
public $user_id;
protected $helpers = ['form', 'url', 'common']; // Loading Helper

public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

    register_CI4($this); // Registering controller instance for helpers;
    $this->user_id = 4;
}
```

Now you will get the controller instance in all other helpers. Suppose a new heper `user_helper` as

```
function show_user_id()
{
    global $CI4;
    echo $CI4->user_id; // Showing 4
}
```

I tested it in  `PHP Version: 8.0.6`

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is the best solution for me:

```
if (!function_exists('getSegment'))
{

    /**
     * Returns segment value for given segment number or false.
     *
     * @param int $number The segment number for which we want to return the value of
     *
     * @return string|false
     */
    function getSegment(int $number)
    {
        $request = \Config\Services::request();

        if ($request->uri->getTotalSegments() >= $number && $request->uri->getSegment($number))
        {
            return $request->uri->getSegment($number);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

source: https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-74755.html

Answer (score 0):

I get it (using CodeIgniter4):

in **controller**:

```
helper('login');      
$isLog=isLogged($this,"user","passwd");

if($isLog)
  ....
  else
  ....
```

in **helper**:

```
use App\Models\Loginmodel as Loginmodel;

function isLogged($ci,$e,$c){
    $ci->login = new Loginmodel;
    $ci->login->Like('paassword',$c);
    $id=$ci->login->select('id')->where('username',$e)->findAll();
    return $id;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In CI4, just use the following:

`$db = model('YourModel');`